# vb6 to vb.net - Guids and classes

Tags: vb.net, vb6

vb.net Object like this

```
<ComClass(WarrantyPrint.ClassId, WarrantyPrint.InterfaceId, WarrantyPrint.EventsId)>
Public Class WarrantyPrint

    Public Const ClassId As String = "3EEDF4AD-78CB-4D9B-8F38-149CA1914AE0"
    Public Const InterfaceId As String = "18343576-609A-473B-804D-03EB4E559FE8"
    Public Const EventsId As String = "390970DD-AABF-42BB-B9F6-6CB6BE5D7248"

    Public Sub initializing
        ' do smth
    End Sub  

    Public Class Towns
        Public Property NameTown As String = ""
        Public Property AddressTown As String = ""
    End Class

    Public Class ListTowns
        Public Property ListTowns() As New List(Of Towns)
    End Class

    Public Sub Add(t As Towns)
        tList.ListTowns.Add(t)
    End Sub
End Class
```

From vb6 i want to set this object like this

```
    Dim ob As Object
    Set ob = CreateObject("Company.Applicat3.laufer.WarrantyPrint")
        ob.Initializing 

    Dim X As Object
    Set X = CreateObject("Company.Applicat3.laufer.WarrantyPrint.towns")
        X.NameTown = "Test"
        X.AddressTown = "123"
        ob.Add (X)

        ob.Show
```

After this i get an error:
activex component can't create object.

Surely i registered this dll under my machine. The proof of that is it show me an error on second object "x" with "ob" everything was fine.

I tried with naming GUID's and puting on the second class but the error is the same.

Comment: "xxx" does not look anything like "x.x.x.WarrantyPrint".  Obfuscating your code is certainly the worst way to ask a question like this.

Comment: Ok now i put "GUID" - s .

Comment: You haven't provided sufficient code to reproduce the problem - for instance `tList` isn't declared in your .net code.

Comment: Public variable insside modul.

Comment: You still have not provided a reproducible example.  What line(s) throw the ActiveX error?  One thing - since the Add member is a Sub, you probably want to use the call verb in your VB6 code: `Call ob.Add(X)`.

Comment: As i said _show me an error on second object "x"_ . So on CreateObject it pop up error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class `WarrantyPrint` there is no class named `Artikli`. This would cause an error. Perhaps the code should use `Towns` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean `Towns` rather than `Artikli` (at the line `Set X = CreateObject("Company.Applicat3.laufer.WarrantyPrint.Artikli")`).

Comment: Error at line `  Set X = CreateObject("Company.Applicat3.laufer.WarrantyPrint.Artikli") `